# Invalid Identifier/Ambiguously Defined

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL statement which ends in:

```
where <table_name>.<column_name> = '<column_value>'
```

I get the following error:

> ORA-00904: "table_name"."column_name": invalid identifier

However, I know that the column is valid for sure. I also tried:

```
where <schema><table_name>.<column_name> = '<column_value>'
```

but got the same error. Lastly I tried without the identifiers:

```
where <column_name> = '<column_value>'
```

but that results in an column is ambiguously defined error.

What am I missing here?

Whole Query:

```
SELECT r.<COLUMN_NAME_1>, r.<COLUMN_NAME_2>, etc, t_append.* 
FROM (
    SELECT <COLUMN_NAME_1>, r.<COLUMN_NAME_2>, etc..
    FROM <TABLE_NAME> ) r
    inner join <TABLE_NAME> t_append on 
        t_append.<COLUMN_NAME_1> = r.<COLUMN_NAME_1> 
    AND t_append.<COLUMN_NAME_2> = r.<COLUMN_NAME_2> 
   AND etc...
   WHERE <TABLE_NAME>.<COLUMN_NAME_1> = '<COLUMN_VALUE1>'
AND <TABLE_NAME>.<COLUMN_NAME_2> = '<COLUMN_VALUE2>'
```

This query takes composite key columns and value and then returns the composite key values followed by the row data which the key represents.

Comment: it should be `<schema>.<table_name>.<column_name>` not `<schema><table_name>.<column_name>`, also you haven't aliased your table in the `FROM` clause have you? if you have used an Alias for the table in the `FROM` clause the you should use the `<Alias>.<ColumnName>`.

Comment: So we can't see the actual query you're trying to run, and all we know is that Oracle claims your query is invalid, but you claim that it is valid. Without a lot more info, my first guess will not be that you are right.

Comment: Show us the FROM clause too. (If you specify schema.table there, you have to specify schema.table.column in the WHERE clause.)

Comment: First I cannot understand why/how are you using ` r.<COLUMN_NAME_2>` on line3 when you don't have any alias `r`, because `r` is a alias of parent query... full query will help more to understand the problem..

Answer (score 0):

The reason of a column ambiguously is because oracle doesn't know which column you are referring , it seems in your query you have specify 2 tables( from tab1 , tab2 ).

As `for "table_name"."column_name": invalid identifier` it means for sure column_name column for table table name doesn't exists, can you provide the ddl of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above mentioned suggesstions,there may two possibilities according to me. You may get

> ORA-00904: "table_name"."column_name": invalid identifier

1) if you don't have **necessary permissions** on the accessing objects. (confirm your permission on the object)

2) if your column was defined with double quotes like below

```
 create table test("CheckMyColumn" number));
```

then it will be **case sensitive**. (Refer the table definition and try with same case)